# Solve $d^2y/dx^2 =k/ y^2$ , where $k$ is constant. I require a solution where I can find $x=f(t)$

Tags: calculus

I have tried using $p=Dy/dx$ and putting $k= dp/dy p y^2$ and doing indefinite integration. Someone please help me out and plz find $x=f(t)$.

Comment: The title equation appears to be separable.  What prompted your attempt to introduce a new variable in this manner?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Switch variables to make the equation
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}= \frac k{y^2}$$ Let $p=x'$
$$-\frac {p'}{p^3}= \frac k{y^2}\implies p= ???$$